# Should I use "dialogue" or "dialogues" for a conversation, i.e. singular or plural?

Tags: usage, singular-vs-plural

This is my first question.

I am trying to figure out the following:

1. In a text, where a conversation is detailed which took place over multiple days, but between the same two people, mostly in direct speech. Should this be mentioned as **a series of dialogues** or **a dialogue**? For example, 'This is a series of dialogues between him and her.' *OR* 'This is a dialogue between him and her.'
2. Somewhere else in the same text, should I refer to the conversations as **dialogues** or **dialogue**? For example, 'These dialogues are different from others.' *OR* 'This dialogue is different from others.'

I think answer to point 1 will answer point 2 to a great extent. Please let me know if more information is required from me.

**EDIT:** Found only this resource where series of dialogues is used to explain the definition. However, I am unable to get a clear idea on whether it should be singular for point 2 or not. Link to researched resource - [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialogue)

Looking forward to learning something new.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why a new contributor's first question is getting downvotes without comments. Care to leave some constructive feedback?

Comment: Have you read my answer about the two meanings??

Answer (score -1):

The OP asked

> Should this be mentioned as *“a series of dialogues”* or *“a dialogue”*?

The OP's reservation is warranted; Google [yields only 83 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20series%20of%20dialogues%22&sxsrf=APwXEde7FInvk59b9GtD3aGcy8qJNJwe6Q:1685268633321&ei=mShzZM6HE9Hn7_UPl7a-kAQ&start=80&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiOuPXx4pf_AhXR87sIHRebD0I4PBDy0wN6BAgCEAs&biw=1120&bih=637&dpr=2.5) for "**a series of dialogues**", which is not very encouraging, but it does suggest that some authors use this particular construction.

The *dialogues* could be with the same two people spread over a period of time  or they may transcribe a number of discussions between different people.

Meanwhile, the noun phrase "**a series of conversations**" produces a slightly more respectable [135 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20series%20of%20dialogue%20sessions%22&sxsrf=APwXEdf5_TqOAIjv8PXS_lWkktZYUopUzg:1685270548404&ei=FDBzZPKWGK6G9u8PnbaM-AQ&start=180&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjy8IyD6pf_AhUug_0HHR0bA084oAEQ8tMDegQIBBAV&biw=1120&bih=637&dpr=2.5). Examples include:

- This book comprises **a series of conversations** between Laura Dern and her mother, the actress Diane Ladd
- …we see the wisdom, humour and curiosity of Richard Feynman **through a series of conversations** with his friend Ralph Leighton.
- (book title) **A Series of Conversations** with a Younger Sister, After Returning from Journeys in France, Italy, Malta, and Turkey

Comment: @Lambie  I agree but why are you telling me?

Comment: The OP already knows that the noun "dialogue" after "series" is plural. The question is whether they should use the singular "dialogue" or the plural "dialogues" . In a movie, we can talk about the *dialogue* as being memorable, effective, etc.   Do we use "dialogue" in the same way between two people if it is repeated and spread over time?

Comment: @Lambie the OP specifically asks: **Somewhere else in the same text, should I refer to the conversations as “dialogues” or “dialogue”?** Google is a source, it provides evidence that the construction "series of dialogues/conversations" is valid.

Comment: Never mind, I changed my mind about what to say here. :)

Answer (score -1):

conversations **over multiple days** can be called: a series of dialogues. That is better than the plural dialogues here.

But *care should be taken here*. **"dialogue" can have a broader meaning used in the singular.** Once you have a basis for discussing something with someone, that "thing" can be the dialogue, the relationship you have established.

**"Over the past weeks, we have managed to find a common dialogue. We are trying to solve the problem. And we hope to continue it will into the future."** There dialogue can be singular as it is an abstract idea. There, **one supposes they have spoken more than once**.

You could end up with all with these two: dialogue and a series of dialogues. "dialogue" ends up being an "abstract noun" in this usage.

"Dialogue is a positive thing. Not having one can be very bad."

However, for the over multiple days, I would use a series of dialogues. But for the relationship, I would call it a dialogue, and not dialogues with an s.

"We established *no dialogue between us* during the five-day conference."

Comment: downvoter: tsk, tsk, tsk.

Answer (score -1):

Both words, *dialogue* and *conversation*, as well as other words such as *discourse*, *discussion* and *debate* can be used differently to mean either a single instance of discussion or speech, or a series of exchanges on a single subject or issue over an extended period of time.

*Examples:*

- I had a conversation with my friend, yesterday.
- We will be having this conversation over the coming weeks.
- We had a debate in class today.
- This debate has been raging for years.
- I have a good dialogue with my employer.
- This is an interesting piece of dialogue.

It may come down to a stylistic choice whether to refer to a series of discussions in the plural or to refer to it as a single discussion, but it could have an impact on meaning - grouping them may demonstrate that they were all on the same theme or collectively part of an organised effort to resolve something.